# R formattable() prevent columns with similar name dropping

Tags: r, formattable

I am using the wonderful package `formattable()` for my shinyApp. Here is a simplified example of the issue I have:

```r
library(formattable)

df <- data.frame(
    ID = LETTERS[1:4], 
    `2018` = c(0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.4), 
    n = c(88, 44, 55, 66), 
    `2019` = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.4), 
    n = c(78, 84, 54, 25))

names(df)[2] <- '2018'
names(df)[4] <- '2019'

formattable(
  df, align = c("l", "r", "l", "r", "l"),
  list(
    `2018` = function(x) percent(x, digits = 1),
    `2019` = function(x) percent(x, digits = 1)
  )
)
```

[image]

This works well, but I would like the column `n.1` to be named `n`. When I rename the column name of `n.1` to `n`, and run the same code to create the table, the last column drops of... It seems that only the first column of any columns with duplicate names are displayed.

```r
names(df)[5] <- "n"

formattable(
  df, align = c("l", "r", "l", "r", "l"),
  list(
    `2018` = function(x) percent(x, digits = 1),
    `2019` = function(x) percent(x, digits = 1)
  )
)
```

How can I present the table with both `n` in the column names?

Comment: In the `data.frame`, call, try with `check.names = FALSE` i.e. `df <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:4], `2018` = c(0.5,0.9,0.8,0.4), n = c(88,44,55,66), `2019`=c(0.9,0.8,0.7,0.4), n=c(78,84,54,25), check.names = FALSE)`

Comment: I still get the same outcome of the second column dropping. It's something in formattable() that causes it to drop, not the data frame that goes in it, I think.

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting on the call to data.frame because you seem to change it back by assignment again.  I think the function takes only a unique column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a matter of display, you may add a space to the name of the second `n` column (with the use of `check.names = FALSE`), as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(ID     = LETTERS[1:4], 
                 `2018` = c(0.5,0.9,0.8,0.4), 
                 n      = c(88,44,55,66), 
                 `2019` = c(0.9,0.8,0.7,0.4), 
                 `n `   = c(78,84,54,25), 
                 check.names = FALSE)

df

formattable(df,
            align=c("l", "r", "l", "r", "l"),
            list(
              `2018` = function(x) percent(x, digits = 1),
              `2019` = function(x) percent(x, digits = 1)
            )
)
```

This will give you the desired output:

[image: output]

Hope you find it useful.